Set Angular signal value as HTML Selected option
I have an angular component that calls for some data asynchronously and stores the value on a signal like this.
tipoSignal: WritableSignal<Tipo> = signal({}) as WritableSignal<Tipo>;


ngOnInit(): void {
   this.tipoService.getTipo().subscribe(tipoReturned =>
      this.tipoSignal.set(tipoReturned)
   );
}

On the HTML side I have a dropdown that allows for selection of other tipo options, like this:
<select class="dropdown" title="tipo_dropdown">
   <option *ngFor="let tipo of tiposArray()" [value]="tipo.id_tipo">{{tipo.formfactor}}</option> 
</select>

tiposArray() also gets populated on ngOnInit*
The problem is I have no idea how to make the value stored on tipoSignal() be selected by default on the dropdown.
I tried adding another option tag and using selected but it doesn't work and even if it did it would create a duplicate entry (since that value is also on tiposArray()). Not sure if it's worth mentioning but a Tipo object only has a unique id and a formfactor, nothing else.
Any suggestions that wouldn't make me have to get rid of signals? (the entire app uses signals everywhere, and this component in particular is plaged with them).

Okay, I figured it out. As @vasilv said, my select tag wasn't bound to anything, so bound it using ngModel and turns out it somehow works with signals too (I don't know why I was convinced it wouldn't work, I feel like I've tried that before with no luck).
The code now looks like this:
<select class="dropdown" title="tipo_dropdown" [(ngModel)]="tipoSignal().id_tipo">
   <option *ngFor="let tipo of tiposArray()" [value]="tipo.id_tipo">{{tipo.formfactor}}</option> 
</select>


In your example code the select is not bound to any model.
To only show the default selected value - the one that will come from tipoSignal you can bind it to the select's value
<select class="dropdown" title="tipo_dropdown" [value]="tipoSignal()?.id_tipo">
   <option *ngFor="let tipo of tiposArray()" [value]="tipo.id_tipo">{{tipo.formfactor}}</option> 
</select>


okay, there's some progress because i do get a selected value, but it's always the first entry on tiposArray(), not the value associated with tipoSignal(). I'm guessing since it's bound it just overrides the value on tipoSignal() with the value selected.

It cannot override tipoSignal value as it is one-way binding and values of signals are set via methods. Are you sure that tipoArray() includes a tipo with the same id_tipo with the id stored in tipoSignal?

Yes, they are defined using the same tipo interface, but I did forget to mention tiposArray() is also a signal, not sure if that has anything to do with it not working with [value]="tipoSignal()?.id_tipo"
